# WSO2 Gmail connector error "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden" while sending a message

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to send a message via Gmail connector by following steps mentioned in WSO2 docx. But I am getting the error "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden".

Comment: 403 Forbidden comes when the credentials are invalid, verify if the token, client id and other things are correct

Comment: Yes I verified all credentials, inside <gmail.init> I have used {userId,accessToken,apiUrl,clientId,clientSecret,refreshToken,accessTokenRegistryPath}, which are correct, but when I am trying to send a message I get the same error